# To get one record if mre than one record exists for same id ,then get only one record based on below condition

Tags: sql, oracle

e.g. If I get 2 null data in a column for same id, then pass null.

ii) If I get 2 same not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 1 null and 1 not null data in a column for same id, then pass not null.

ii) If I get 2 different not null data in a column for same id, then pass '?'.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd0Mv.png)

Please find the sample data in the image.

Thanks in advance.

Output obtained after new code:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A8fH.png)

Comment: Here you find something useful on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]. Also, please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the sample data like image in below SQL.If the column data type is varchar(char) please delete the TO_CHAR expression, and replace the table name TEST_TABLE to your table's.

```
WITH TEST_TABLE AS (
SELECT 1056059 AS PRTY_KEY_ID, NULL AS TOT_ASSET_AM, NULL AS TOT_LIABILITIES_AM, NULL AS DBUS_NM, 'Pediatrics' AS BUS_NATURE_DE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1056059 AS PRTY_KEY_ID, 5000 AS TOT_ASSET_AM, '300000' AS TOT_LIABILITIES_AM, NULL AS DBUS_NM, 'Medicine' AS BUS_NATURE_DE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    PRTY_KEY_ID,
    MIN(CASE WHEN TOT_ASSET_AM_CNT > 1 THEN '?' ELSE TO_CHAR(TOT_ASSET_AM) END) AS TOT_ASSET_AM,
    MIN(CASE WHEN TOT_LIABILITIES_AM_CNT > 1 THEN '?' ELSE TO_CHAR(TOT_LIABILITIES_AM) END) AS TOT_LIABILITIES_AM,
    MIN(CASE WHEN DBUS_NM_CNT > 1 THEN '?' ELSE TO_CHAR(DBUS_NM) END) AS DBUS_NM,
    MIN(CASE WHEN BUS_NATURE_DE_CNT > 1 THEN '?' ELSE TO_CHAR(BUS_NATURE_DE) END) AS BUS_NATURE_DE
FROM (
    SELECT 
        TEST_TABLE.*,
        COUNT(TOT_ASSET_AM) OVER(PARTITION BY PRTY_KEY_ID) AS TOT_ASSET_AM_CNT,
        COUNT(TOT_LIABILITIES_AM) OVER(PARTITION BY PRTY_KEY_ID) AS TOT_LIABILITIES_AM_CNT,
        COUNT(DBUS_NM) OVER(PARTITION BY PRTY_KEY_ID) AS DBUS_NM_CNT,
        COUNT(BUS_NATURE_DE) OVER(PARTITION BY PRTY_KEY_ID) AS BUS_NATURE_DE_CNT
    FROM TEST_TABLE
)
GROUP BY PRTY_KEY_ID
```

Comment: Thank you..but your query is partially correct.For 2 different not null value , I'm getting '?' but if you check the sample data for TOT_LIABILITIES_AM, one is null and other is not null for same id. so i need that not null value.

Comment: I have updated my answer and tested it and the before one, both of them returns the result you excepted like [1056059,5000,300000,NULL,?].

Comment: Please check the image result , I have attached in my question.

Comment: It seems TOT_ASSET_AM & TOT_LIABILITIES_AM also have multiple values are not the DBNull.

Comment: I updated my answer with dummy data. It returns the correct result in my oracle envirment.

Comment: Is the not dbnull value only one?

Comment: Is there any other way to deal with this.

Comment: sorry to explain unclearly. dbnull means database original null not the [null] char value.

Comment: there is one dbnull and one not null.

Comment: what is the result of my current answer in you environment?

Comment: [1056059,?,?,NULL,?]

Comment: Don't delete the with expression, just execute my sql directly. I have no idea if it still return the incorrect result. "COUNT returns the number of rows where expr is not null", if TOT_LIABILITIES_AM returns [?] It means the COUNT  took value > 1 that means > 1 expr are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following :

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN PRTY_KEY_ID_NN= 0 THEN NULL /* IF BOTH/ALL VALUES ARE NULL */)
             WHEN PRTY_KEY_ID_NN <> TOTAL_COUNT THEN PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_MX 
             ELSE 
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT=PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_DIST THEN NULL /* IF BOTH HAVING DIFFERENT NOT NULL VALUE */
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT<>PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_DIST THEN PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_MX
                END
        END)PRTY_KEY_ID_VAL,
        (CASE WHEN TOTAL_ASSET_A_NN= 0 THEN NULL /* IF BOTH/ALL VALUES ARE NULL */)
             WHEN TOTAL_ASSET_A_NN <> TOTAL_COUNT THEN TOTAL_ASSET_A_MX 
             ELSE 
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT=TOTAL_ASSET_A_DIST THEN NULL /* IF BOTH HAVING DIFFERENT NOT NULL VALUE */
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT<>TOTAL_ASSET_A_DIST THEN TOTAL_ASSET_A_MX
                END
        END)TOTAL_ASSET_VAL,
        (CASE WHEN DBUS_NUM_NN= 0 THEN NULL /* IF BOTH/ALL VALUES ARE NULL */)
             WHEN DBUS_NUM_NN <> TOTAL_COUNT THEN DBUS_NUM_MX 
             ELSE 
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT=DBUS_NUM_DIST THEN NULL /* IF BOTH HAVING DIFFERENT NOT NULL VALUE */
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT<>DBUS_NUM_DIST THEN DBUS_NUM_MX
                END
        END)DBUS_NUM_DIST_VAL,
        (CASE WHEN BUS_NATURE_DE_NN= 0 THEN NULL /* IF BOTH/ALL VALUES ARE NULL */)
             WHEN BUS_NATURE_DE_NN <> TOTAL_COUNT THEN BUS_NATURE_DE_MX 
             ELSE 
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT=BUS_NATURE_DE_DIST THEN NULL /* IF BOTH HAVING DIFFERENT NOT NULL VALUE */
                CASE WHEN TOTAL_COUNT<>BUS_NATURE_DE_DIST THEN BUS_NATURE_DE_MX
                END
        END)BUS_NATURE_DE_VAL
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*)TOTAL_COUNT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PRTY_KEY_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)PRTY_KEY_ID_NN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOTAL_ASSET_A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)TOTAL_ASSET_A_NN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOTAL_LIAB_A IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)TOTAL_LIAB_A_NN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DBUS_NUM IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)DBUS_NUM_NN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BUS_NATURE_DE IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)BUS_NATURE_DE_NN,
       MAX(PRTY_KEY_ID_NN)PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_MX,
       MAX(TOTAL_ASSET_A)TOTAL_ASSET_A_MX,
       MAX(TOTAL_LIAB_A)TOTAL_LIAB_A_MX,
       MAX(DBUS_NUM)DBUS_NUM_MX,
       MAX(BUS_NATURE_DE)BUS_NATURE_DE_MX,
       COUNT(DISTINCT PRTY_KEY_ID_NN) PRTY_KEY_ID_NN_DIST,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TOTAL_ASSET_A)TOTAL_ASSET_A_DIST,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TOTAL_LIAB_A)TOTAL_LIAB_A_DIST,
       COUNT(DISTINCT DBUS_NUM)DBUS_NUM_DIST,
       COUNT(DISTINCT BUS_NATURE_DE)BUS_NATURE_DE_DIST
FROM YOUR_TABLE)
```